# Get-ChildItem and 'DIR' return different file/folder counts?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder on file-share that I would like to migrate to SharePoint.

But there is this problem. I have given myself a full control on the folder and its sub-folders and files. Also I made myself owner of all as well.

I use Recursively count all files and folders, I get total 54,712 files

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
```

When I click right and properties . I get 50,750 files and 4,615 folders . So makes up 55,365 items in total.

With command prompt using `dir *.* /w /s` I get total 63,939

So, which one is the most reliable number of files and folders here? Why am I getting different numbers here?

Also 55,364 files has been migrated to SharePoint online.

Comment: without the `-Force` parameter, you will NOT see any of the hidden or system files. try this `(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -File -Recurse -Force).Count` and then run it a 2nd time without the `-Force` to see the difference. i get 530 files with the 1st, & 506 files with the 2nd.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Oh well i get 158 files for with and without  -Force .

Comment: you may not have any hidden or system files in your temp folder tree. [*grin*] does it make any difference with your share location?